# SQL data execution plan

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-execution-plan

Does

`SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM TABLE`

return the same data execution plan as

`SELECT * FROM TABLE`?

Please also let me know if this should be moved to ServerFault.

Thanks.

Comment: The query plans for the queries you've given will be trivial with no scope for the optimiser to do anything with. Are your actual queries any more complicated than that? Are you inserting into another table or something because there might be scope to optimise that.

Comment: @Martin - All of the scripts are between 4 and 7 Joins large. I will play around with the TOP a bit.

Comment: Ah I see I thought that there must be more to it than that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for yourself. In SSMS, go to Query -> Include Actual Execution Plan

Then run your queries.

e.g. when I run:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM sys.tables
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```

They return different execution plans.

Comment: For a single table though (rather than view) I can't imagine it would ever be the case.

Comment: I am on a time crunch and the queries could run upwards of 8 hours. So I was looking for a way to sort of get around it.

Comment: @Jim - You can look at estimated query plans as well.

Comment: @Martin - technically, the execution plan is different for a single table (try it) as it will include a "TOP" operator in the plan. But my main point is, "try it and see with your specific query"

Comment: @MartinSmith - I have been doing that as well. I didn't know if there was significant differences between estimated and actual. Thanks.